# Getting [Fatal error: exception Out_of_memory] using Cairo.PNG.create in OCaml

Tags: image, ocaml, cairo

I use Cairo.PNG.create to read images in OCaml.
I get

```
Fatal error: exception Out_of_memory
```

when I try to read some images. They are 5KB, but there are images whose size is 5KB I can read. I can read bigger images(ex. 45KB), so I don't think the cause of the error is a image's size. However, I can't find  common points with images I can't read except the size.
When do I get the error using Cairo.PNG.create in OCaml? I want hints to delete the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cairo.PNG.create` is a [thin wrapper](https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-cairo/blob/master/src/cairo_stubs.c#L1598) around the C function [`cairo_image_surface_create_from_png`](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-PNG-Support.html#cairo-image-surface-create-from-png).  It [raises `Out_of_memory`](https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-cairo/blob/master/src/cairo_ocaml_types.c#L71) when the C function returns [`CAIRO_STATUS_NO_MEMORY`](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Error-handling.html#CAIRO-STATUS-NO-MEMORY:CAPS).  Since this is done before any memory is allocated, I do not think this is a bug in the wrapper.  Could you report the result of the command `file` on your images?

Comment: I tried the command and I found the format of images I can't read is GIF. When I looked at information of images on Finder, the format is PNG. So, I mistook the format is quite PNG. It's embarrassing,  but I don't know this kind of situation. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Something else to check is whether the images you're reading are well formed. Maybe the images describe themselves as being gigantic. I believe I've seen some rogue PNG formats where the size looks absurdly large.

Comment: I could delete the error as written in a comment to ChirS. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0):

This kinds of errors are usually a sign of memory corruption. You should look take a look at all calls to `Marshal` module, either direct or indirect (like `input_value`). They are usually cause of evil. Otherwise, the possible candidates are bugs in `C`-bindings. This kinds of errors are very hard to find and debug.

P.S. And, to make sure that this is indeed a memory corruption, you should look at the `dmesg` output. If it is not a memory corruption, then there must be notes from OOM killer, something like "killing all children, etc". But I'm pretty sure that you won't see anything like this, as applications killed with OOM usually finish with last word: "Killed".

Comment: I could delete the error as written in a comment to ChirS. Thank you for replying.